# Find relative paths in css content

Tags: php

I'm finishing developing a custom css merge system on a website.
I already have the resulting css merged, from all the css included.

But I'm finding one problem, with content that includes relative urls.

For example:

```
background: url('../../img/ratingicon.png') no-repeat center bottom transparent;
```

The function that adds the content of each css, to the merged css, is the following:

```
/**
 * fn adding css merge
 * @param $merged_css_path example of value: /themes/movic/assets/css/merged.css
 * @param $css_path example of value: /themes/movic/assets/css/theme.css
*/
private function addMergedCSS($merged_css_path, $css_path)
{
  $uri = $this->getFQDN() . $this->getUriFromPath($css_path); //example of value: https://mydomain.test/themes/movic/assets/css/theme.css
  $content = file_get_contents(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.$merged_css_path); //_PS_ROOT_DIR_ value is shared/httpd/myfolder/htdocs
  $content .= file_get_contents($uri);
  $content = $this->fixPathsUrlsProblem($content, $css_path);
  file_put_contents(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.$merged_css_path, $content); //_PS_ROOT_DIR_ value is shared/httpd/myfolder/htdocs
}
```

I thought about using the function:

```
fixPathsUrlsProblem($content, $css_path)
```

which receives the content of the css, as well as its path, and does the following:

1. In $content, it looks for strings of the style ../ or ../../ ( or ../../../ )
2. Based on the parameter $css_path, **it replaces the relative path with the absolute path**. One $css_path value is, for example: /themes/movic/assets/css/theme.css

Can you help me?
A greeting and thank you very much in advance,

Comment: do you want obsolute path or do you want relative path ?

Comment: @DickensAS absolute path

Comment: if you want absolute path like full unix path `/opt/myfolder/mywebsite/img/ratingicon.png` , I need to know how this function `$this->getFQDN()` works, I can see `$uri` , you simply pass it to that function second parameter as `$this->fixPathsUrlsProblem($content, $uri);`

Comment: sorry, I'm updating the ask

Comment: @DickensAS I just updated the ask. The functions getFQDN() obtains the base url of the site.

Comment: thanks, may I know the value of `_PS_ROOT_DIR_` I think it will be the actual path of the website linux folder location

Comment: @DickensAS of course, that value is /shared/httpd/myfolder/htdocs I'm in local environment. I use Docker.

Comment: You have repeated `file_get_contents` twice may I know why , I think the second call `$content .= file_get_contents($uri);` is the problem

Comment: try passing paramter like this `$this->fixPathsUrlsProblem($content,_PS_ROOT_DIR_.$merged_css_path)` and try to remove that two time call